# Swift - Injecting and storing protocols

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a mapper as follows

```swift
protocol MapperProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype U
    func map(item: T) -> U?
}
```

And I want to inject it to a class as follows

```swift
protocol ParserProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype U
    func parse(from: T) -> U?
}

class TrackParser: ParserProtocol {
    typealias T = String
    typealias U = Track
    
    private let mapper: MapperProtocol
    
    init(mapper: MapperProtocol) {
        self.mapper = mapper
    }
    
    func parse(from path: String) -> Track? {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(filePath: path)) else { return nil }
        return mapper.map(item: data)
    }
}
```

`TrackParser` will be initialised from somewhere else so it doesn't need to know the concrete type of the mapper.

When I want to implement it that way I get the following error.
[image: Error screenshot]
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the `parse` implementation requires that the mapper has `T == Data` and `U == Track`, but you haven't specified those constraint anywhere in `TrackParser`.

We can make `T` and `U` the [primary associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0346-light-weight-same-type-syntax.md) of `MapperProtocol`, so that the same-type requirements can be specified very easily as `MapperProtocol<Data, Track>`.

```
protocol MapperProtocol<T, U> { // Notice the "<T, U>"
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype U
    func map(item: T) -> U?
}
```

Also, starting from Swift 5.7, existential types are required to be prefixed with "`any`", so you would write:

```
private let mapper: any MapperProtocol<Data, Track>

init(mapper: any MapperProtocol<Data, Track>) {
    self.mapper = mapper
}
```