# Swift : generic combination of two operations

Tags: swift, operation

I'd like to implement an aux class to build a chain of Operations. For this I have a code :

```
import Foundation

protocol OperationDataInterface {
    associatedtype In
    associatedtype Out
    
    var inData: In { get set }
    var outData: Out { get set }
}

typealias CombinedOperation = Operation & OperationDataInterface

class CombinationsOfTwoOperations {
    private var firstOperation: any CombinedOperation
    private var secondOperation: any CombinedOperation
    private var joinOperation: Operation
    
    init(firstOp: any CombinedOperation, secondOp: any CombinedOperation) {
        firstOperation = firstOp
        secondOperation = secondOp
    }
    
    func build() {
        joinOperation = BlockOperation() { [unowned self] in
            self.secondOperation.inData = self.firstOperation.outData
        }
        
        joinOperation.addDependency(firstOperation)
        secondOperation.addDependency(joinOperation)
    }
}
```

But I get a compilation issue :
[image]

Is it prohibited to assign generics to each other? Is it possible to overcome this problem?

Comment: Imagine `In` is `Int` and `Out` is `String`...

Comment: Can you remove the typealias and do `protocol CombinedOperation<In, Out> where Self: Operation {` instead? If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74164963/5133585) should answer your question.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for your note ! I got it and I'ma post a solution here in a moment